# The iframe closes (via onclick="self.parent.tb_remove();) in Firefox and IE7 but it doesn't close in Chrome

Tags: jquery, iframe

The code:

Html:

```
<p>View full-size photo <a href="iframeModal.html?placeValuesBeforeTB_=savedValues&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=800&modal=true" title="The descripttion goes here." class="thickbox">here</a>.</p>
```

Iframe:

```
  <input id="Login" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;Ok&nbsp;&nbsp;" onclick="self.parent.tb_remove();" type="submit">
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @hello_there_andy Please avoid making insignificant edits. Please have a read: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276402/100-edits-in-one-evening-is-it-wrong/276435#276435

Answer (score 1):

I'd try `window.parent.tb_remove()`; I don't know what "self" is and I don't know what "tb_remove" is and, overall, I don't really understand the situation, however.